# ¿Por qué el método "Thread.stop()" está deprecado?

Tags: java, hilos

Necesito entender que son los métodos deprecated, más en concreto en el método stop de la clase Thread. ¿Por qué no se debe utilizar este método?.He estado ojeando en la API la explicación, pero no lo entiendo bien. Dice lo siguiente:

```
 @deprecated This method is inherently unsafe.  Stopping a thread with
 *       Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it
 *       has locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked
 *       <code>ThreadDeath</code> exception propagating up the stack).  If
 *       any of the objects previously protected by these monitors were in
 *       an inconsistent state, the damaged objects become visible to
 *       other threads, potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior.  Many
 *       uses of <code>stop</code> should be replaced by code that simply
 *       modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should
 *       stop running.  The target thread should check this variable
 *       regularly, and return from its run method in an orderly fashion
 *       if the variable indicates that it is to stop running.  If the
 *       target thread waits for long periods (on a condition variable,
 *       for example), the <code>interrupt</code> method should be used to
 *       interrupt the wait.
```

En el siguiente enlace también lo explican pero es más de ello mismo. [Deprecated Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda? ¿Qué significa `@deprecated` o la explicación de porqué este método ya no se debe usar?

Comment: Ya he modificado la pregunta. Por lo que he visto, deprecated se asocio a métodos que no son seguros y no deberían ser utilizados.

Comment: Deprecated significa obsoleto aunque sigue funcionando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los métodos deprecados, son métodos que fueron reemplazados por otros que cumplen su misma función pero que han sido optimizados a lo largo de las versiones.

Con respecto a que metodos se pueden utilizar para no usar le Thread.stop, puedes mirar éste enlace https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/THI05-J.+Do+not+use+Thread.stop%28%29+to+terminate+threads

Hay un par de funciones que pueden ayudarte con lo que necesitas.

Answer (score -1):

Cuando trabajas con *Threads* y similares, tienes *concurrencia*; múltiples hilos de ejecución trabajando en paralelo.

Por ejemplo, tienes un *thread* A que se encarga de, cada segundo, modificar un bitmap para mostrar la hora y otro *thread* B que muestra ese bitmap en pantalla.

Cuando tienes esto, quieres evitar que B muestre el bitmap mientras A todavía lo está generando, porque estaría a medio hacer (*inconsistent state*), y usas *sincronización* para que B se quede bloqueado mientras A genera el nuevo bitmap (y viceversa).

Pero si haces *stop*, la ejecución de A acaba *immediatamente*; A deja el bitmap "inconsistente" y B (que ya no está bloqueado) lo coge y lo muestra.

Si en vez de un bitmap A está modificando una estructura de datos interna, puede hacer mucho daño. Y los errores de sincronización suelen ser difíciles de detectar, reproducir y depurar, ya que a menudo puedes parar A sin que cause efectos secundarios.

Así que en vez de usar `stop`, tienes que poner algún variable a un valor específico para que, de vez en cuando, *cuando sea seguro*, A compruebe ese valor y si ve que le indica que pare, pare sin dejar datos inconsistentes.